# JAVA_HOME not working

Tags: java, setup, bash

I can't set up `JAVA_HOME`. Before you dismiss this as a noob's question who can't figure out how to Google things let me explain my situation.

I bought RaspberryPi and installed Raspbian onto an SD card following tutorial steps. Everything seemed normal until I started tinkering with it and installing some stuff like `maven`, `tomcat`, `logstash` or `solr`.

Every tool complained about not finding `java` in `JAVA_HOME`. No biggie. I found `which java`, followed some symbolic links to find java in `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/bin/java`. Java came with my Raspbian I did not install it. So I added:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm-vfp-hflt"
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

at the end of `~/.bashrc` I'm no sysadmin but I did that a couple of times so no worries.

I was wrong. Regardless of where I put those lines (`/etc/environment, ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile`) `JAVA_HOME` doesn't seem to be set up. When I `echo $JAVA_HOME` lo and behold there it is, pointing as supposed to.

When I type `mvn -v` it returns:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm-vfp-hflt/bin/java
```

So I checked permissions:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -laR /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3384 Dec  9  2015 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/bin/java
```

But everyone has `+x`

I tried rebooting, using `source`, nothing works. I'm out of ideas. Please help me Raspberry aficionados.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `JAVA_HOME` points to a different directory than where your `java` executable is located. Per your question, the JAVA_HOME directory is:

`/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm-vfp-hflt`

whereas `java` is located in

`/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt`

Note the `arm` vs. `arm32`.

Comment: Of course it had to be my stupidity...